# Entity Framework Extensions: Can't BulkMerge entities with empty identity property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-extensions

I uses `BulkMerge` method of Entity Framework Extensions for insert/update large collections of entities. Entity table have identity column `Id` that used as a primary key. When I try to BulkMerge collection with several newly created entities (they have Id = 0 by default) it throws such exception: `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Users'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users'. The duplicate key value is (0)`. Btw, `BulkInsert` method with same entities works fine. I tried to use options like `AutoMapOutputDirection`, `InsertIfNotExists` or `MergeKeepIdentity` but they were ineffective. Can anyone suggest the correct options for proper BulkMerge work or any other ways to solve issue?

Comment: Seems like your Id column is not autoincrement primary key. Have you tried insert just one row and check if Id column has a new value ?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's turned out to be not autoincrement. But why BulkInsert works fine with empty Id?

Comment: So you need to make your id autoincrement. Then bulkinsert will work with entities with id = 0.

Comment: Do you know if BulkMerging updates the entity objects? (like SaveChanges does)? I want to get the new inserted objects after a bulk merge but I don't know a way to retrieve them